# Chrome/Firefox Layout Great - Safari appearing broken - no floats used

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout, safari

I have a parent div (`#trial`) with two inner divs (`#wp` & `#wp1`) side by side. `#wp` consists of an h1 display block above an image and then to the side there is a small sign up form for the "trial" service (This is a project website, not the real thing).

In Chrome and Firefox the layout appears correctly. I just realized in Safari the second div breaks. The form is to the right, but appears offset below the first div.

This is my html:

```
<div id = "trial"> <!-- Register div -->
    <div id = "wp">
<h1 class = "COA">Make your home a SMART home.</h1>
    <img src = "images/homedim.png" alt = "HomeSmart">
        </div>
    <div id="wp1">
        <h2>Sign up NOW for a free 30-day trial.</h2>
        <form id = "register" method = "post">
            <fieldset>
                <div class = "required">
                    <label for = "fname">What is your first name?</label>
                    <input id = "fname" type = "text" placeholder = "first     name" required aria-required = "true">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div class = "required">
                    <label for = "lname">What is your last name?</label>
                    <input id = "lname" type = "text" placeholder = "last name" required aria-required = "true">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div class = "required">
                    <label for = "email">Your email address</label>
                    <input id = "email" name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "user@mydomain.com" required aria-required = "true">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div class = "required">
                    <label for = "email1">Re-type your email address</label>
                    <input id = "email1" name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "user@mydomain.com" required aria-required = "true">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <p>You will receive an email to confirm your trial.</p>
            <fieldset>
                <div class= "submit">
                    <p>
                        <input class="submit_btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="submit();" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div> <!--End of Register Div -->
```

The css is as follows:

```
/*Beginning of bottom half for welcome page*/
#trial{
    margin-top: 1.625em;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#trial h1 {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1.250em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: 1.563em;
}
#wp{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.250em;
}
#wp1{
    margin-right: 1.875em;
    margin-top: 1.875em;
}
#wp1 h2{
    /*width: 100%;*/
    text-align: right;
}
#wp1 form{
    text-align: right;
   /* width: 100%;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1.250em;
}
#wp1 .submit_btn{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    width:43%;
    height: 2.5em;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 1.250em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #c87346; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%, #f4ba52 100%); /*   FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c87346), color-stop(100%,#f4ba52)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* W3C */
}
#wp img, #wp h1 {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 1.250em;
    margin-top: .938em;
}
/*end of bottom half of welcome page #trial*/
```

Any advice (and critiques) would greatly be appreciated so I can get this displaying correctly in all three browsers please?  (Even non-associated things not related to the specific problem).
If my images upload, the safari image is after I just now commented out the width: 100%; which pulled the div over to the center in safari, but in Chrome and Firefox, all is well.

Thank you in advance.

I could not upload images due to not having enough rep yet, but it can be seen here [Project](http://jlsdesk.com/lab/School_Projects/LtName_FName_PWA2/index.html)

Again I appreciate any advice and inputs.

UPDATE 5/8/2015
I was able to resolve my problem by adding float:left; to the left-most div and parent container.  Some margin tweaks and css clean up and all works well.

```
#trial{
    margin-top: 1.625em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wp{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;

}
#wp h1 {
    width: 45%;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: .938em;
}
#wp img {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 1.25em;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#wp1{
   margin-right: 1em;
   margin-top: 1.875em;
}
#wp1 h2{
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
#wp1 form{
   text-align: right;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 1.250em;
}
#wp1 .submit_btn{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    width:43%;
    height: 2.5em;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #c87346; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%, #f4ba52 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c87346), color-stop(100%,#f4ba52)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* W3C */
```

So much for thinking this could be done without floats.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 5/8/2015 I was able to resolve my problem by adding float:left; to the left-most div and parent container. Some margin tweaks and css clean up and all works well.  So much for thinking it could be done without floats.

```
#trial{
margin-top: 1.625em;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}

#wp{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;

}
#wp h1 {
width: 45%;
text-align: left;
display: block;
height: auto;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: .938em;
}
#wp img {
float: left;
width: 45%;
margin-top: 1.25em;
margin-left: 50px;
}
#wp1{
 margin-right: 1em;
 margin-top: 1.875em;
}
#wp1 h2{
text-align: right;
margin-right: 1em;
}
#wp1 form{
text-align: right;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 1.250em;
}
#wp1 .submit_btn{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
width:43%;
height: 2.5em;
font-size:1em;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
-ms-border-radius: 30px;
-o-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
background: #c87346; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%, #f4ba52 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c87346), color-stop(100%,#f4ba52)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c87346 0%,#f4ba52 100%); /* W3C */
```